# Did Actually needs to add fragments in mainfest

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId
    if (id ==R.id.refreshtabbutton){
        val intent : Intent = Intent(this,frag2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Error

```
   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class      {com.example.vlcclone/com.example.vlcclone.frag2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
   at com.example.vlcclone.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:54)
```

How  to solve this issue? I want to open fragment when user clicks on the refresh button which is present in menu.

Comment: "i want to open fragment when user clicks on the refreh button which is present in menu" -- you do not use `startActivity()` to display a fragment. Either use [a `FragmentTransaction` with a `FragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) or use [the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation).

Comment: @CommonsWare idont have to replace any fragment but i have to open fragment which is already present

Comment: then you create a new activity and add the fragment to that activity using a fragment transaction. Then you launch this new activity via an intent.

Answer (score 1):

The fragments are not opened using Intents. You should create an activity that holds your second Fragment, or you should replace current fragment with the second (in case if you have container for holding the fragment inside your current activity). Intent is only for opening the Activity, not Fragment (!)

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments go through this